# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 when connecting with nodejs program

Tags: javascript, node-postgres, postgresql-12, centos8

I have a postgresql server set up on a CentOS 8 machine, and a js program running on the same machine, using the `pg` library.

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.PG_USER,      //postgres user
    host: process.env.PG_ENDPOINT,  //localhost (I also tried 127.0.0.1)
    database: process.env.PG_DB,    //database name to connect to
    password: process.env.PG_PASS,  //postgres user password
    port: process.env.PG_PORT       //5432
});
```

I set up the pg Pool correctly, and it works just fine if I want to connect it to my AWS postgres server (with the correct endpoint and such, of course), but when I try to get it to connect to the postgres server I have set up on the same machine, I get the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
```

I followed the directions to set up the pg_hba.conf file to supposedly allow for password login instead of ident:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

and in the postgresql.conf I uncommented the `listen_addresses` and `port` lines:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = 'localhost'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /tmp'  # comma-separated list of directories
```

Any help is appreciated.

Result of netstat -na:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ###.##.43.124:22        ###.##.122.136:59611   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     64 ###.##.43.124:22        ###.##.122.136:59445   ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7
```

(# used to hide IP)

Comment: Try killing port `5432` with `lsof -t -i tcp:5432 | xargs kill -9` then re-connecting.

Comment: @RandyCasburn that doesn't really help, but I did try the netstat command like someone did in the comments. I added the result to my original question.

Comment: @TobiahRex It's saying "not enough arguments" when using ```lsof -t -i tcp:5432 | xargs kill -9```

Comment: @K.Sutherland Try without the `-9` as in `lsof -t -i tcp:5432 | xargs kill`

Answer (score 5):

The `netstat` doesn't show anything listening at 5432, which is where you've told PostgreSQL to listen. If it's not listening, you can't connect to it. Why isn't it listening? Maybe it's not running -- you should check its log files and see what happened.